# Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed error in console application

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, console-application, streamreader

I have this code in console application and it runs in a loop

```
 try
 {
      HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(search);
      request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "de-DE");
      request.Method = "GET";
      request.Accept = "text/html";
      using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
      {
           using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(),
                    Encoding.ASCII))
           {
                string html = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    FindForMatch(html, url);
           }
      }
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
      throw new Exception(ex.Message);
 }
```

after few loops it gives

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed

error. any idea why this happen? thanx..

Comment: Could be anything. Perhaps the server dont like you hammering it.

Comment: Btw, don't re-throw your exception, better log your exception or let the exception bubble up to a higher location, and catch it there

Comment: exception come from `reader.ReadToEnd()'

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After adding

```
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
```

it works fine..

I found it form this blog post

[WebRequest and Unable to read data from the transport connection Error](http://sysrc.code4beer.org/2009/06/30/webrequest-unable-to-read-from-transport/)

Comment: Hmm, I have no idea why this works, but it does! Weird! Maybe it's IIS Express or something.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked in my case, I was struggling for some time.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the code, looping 10 times to load google.com and it worked for me. Is there something special about `search` - perhaps try replacing it with another uri. I did not include `findForMatch` - I assume it is not doing anything that would cause the exception.

Comment: its not happening all the time. exception come from `reader.ReadToEnd()'

Answer (score -5):

Try disposing the reader in the finally block of your try catch