# Service HTTP Post is receiving "Existing Connection Was Forcibly Closed"

Tags: c#, httprequest, windows-authentication

I have a windows service that I am trying to get running on a server. It just posts data to a php page and has further logic based on the response back. This works 100% on my machine and 100% on the server WHEN Anonymous Authenication is turned on for the website(IIS).

What I want to accomplish is to run the site with Windows Authenication turned ON and have my service still work... except when I try this I receive a nice EventLog entry.

> "System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport
>   connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
>   host"

I am running the service under an account that has all required permissions. So I understand that "CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials" should use this account for authentication( I am not receiving a 401 error ,but not ruling it out )

Below is my HttpPost code, I have set quite a few options from other posts trying to find a solution.

```
            string postData = xml;
            //--------------
            HttpRequestCachePolicy policy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy   MontgP02(HttpRequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
            HttpWebRequest.DefaultCachePolicy = policy;

            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            //Initialisation
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
            HttpWebRequest WebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            //Credentials
            WebReq.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            WebReq.PreAuthenticate = true;
            WebReq.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

            //Request Settings
            WebReq.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
            //WebReq.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 1;
            WebReq.Method = "POST";
            WebReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            //The length of the buffer 
            WebReq.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
            //Set timeout
            WebReq.Timeout = 25000;
            //Use Proxy or Not
            if (useproxy == "ON")
            {
                WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy();
                // Create a new Uri object.
                Uri newUri = new Uri(proxy);

                // Associate the new Uri object to the myProxy object.
                myProxy.Address = newUri;
                WebReq.Proxy = myProxy;

            }

            try
            {
                //Send Data
                using (Stream requestStream = WebReq.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    // write to stream
                    //write, and close. 
                    requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex) {
 MessageLog("ERROR: Sending Data : " + ex.ToString() + ":", "ERROR"); 
          }


            //Get Response
            try
            {
                using (System.Net.WebResponse response = WebReq.GetResponse())
                {
                    Stream Answer = response.GetResponseStream();
                    // read from stream
                    StreamReader _Answer = new StreamReader(Answer);
                    PostResponse = _Answer.ReadToEnd();

                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
 MessageLog("ERROR: Receiving Response : " + ex.ToString() + ":" , "ERROR"); 
              }


             }
        catch (WebException ex)
            {

MessageLog("ERROR Posting " + ex.ToString() + ":" + PostResponse, "ERROR");
            }

        }
```

I understand from the error that the server is cutting the connection before I can complete the request. This happens everytime on the server negating thoughts of timeouts I would think. 
Having looked around other fourms, I am at a loss , having tried other variations etc the fact that it does work fine with authenication off leads me to think it may be a setting in IIS or something else down the authenication route.

Any insight welcome

Comment: Might be a bit of an odd question, but does this happen in every browser?

Comment: Its a windows service that hits a php page, what browser are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry misunderstood. Have you tried the suggestions in this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323584/unable-to-read-data-from-the-transport-connection-the-connection-was-closed-err

Comment: Yes with no luck, I have tried setting the keep alive/protocol and tried different variations just to rule them out.