# IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I'm getting this error while trying to posting web service with http:

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was
>   closed

some similar question: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323584/unable-to-read-data-from-the-transport-connection-the-connection-was-closed-err)

My code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "POST";
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 24;

string dataText = items.ToString();
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataText);
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    requestStream.Close();
}

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
string responseFromServer;
using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    response.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

I've commented the line code of:

```
//requestStream.Close();
```

the `KeepAlive`make the the http connection to be persistent connection,
it only closing at the end of the connection, the `Close()` make it throw exception.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection